# How to select records from one table that does not exits in second table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables.

**T1**
IDWorker
Name
Lastname

**T2**
IDWorker
Month
Year
Factor

Now I have to get all Workers that are not in T2 for given Month and Year.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  `T1`.`IDWorker`,
  `T1`.`Name`,
  `T1`.`LastName`,
  `T2`.`Month`,
  `T2`.`Year`
  `T2`.`Factor`
FROM
  `T1`
  LEFT JOIN `T2` ON `T1`.`IDWorker` = `T2`.`IDWorker`
WHERE
  `T2`.`Month` = 4 AND
  `T2`.`Year` = 2014 AND
  `T2`.`IDWorker` IS NULL;
```

Running this query i get empty result, but excluding month and year criteria I get list of workers. I need results with that shows all workers that are not entered in T2 for given period.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE IDWorker NOT IN (SELECT IDWorker 
                       FROM T2 
                       WHERE Month = 4 
                       AND Year = 2014)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT
  `t`.`IDWorker`,
  `t`.`Name`,
  `t`.`LastName`,
  `T2`.`Month`,
  `T2`.`Year`
  `T2`.`Factor`
FROM
  `T1` t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM `T2`
WHERE
  `T2`.`Month` = 4 AND
  `T2`.`Year` = 2014 AND
`t`.`IDWorker` = `T2`.`IDWorker`
)
```

Or other  way to add your where conditions of table 2 in `ON()` clause

```
SELECT
  `T1`.`IDWorker`,
  `T1`.`Name`,
  `T1`.`LastName`,
  `T2`.`Month`,
  `T2`.`Year`
  `T2`.`Factor`
FROM
  `T1`
  LEFT JOIN `T2` ON `T1`.`IDWorker` = `T2`.`IDWorker` AND
  `T2`.`Month` = 4 AND
  `T2`.`Year` = 2014 
WHERE
  `T2`.`IDWorker` IS NULL;
```

Also go through [***LEFT JOIN / IS NULL vs. NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS: nullable columns***](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=24888) for performance factor

Comment: I've tried with second query and it works. But if I enter different month, for example 5 that I also get list of workers even there is no records for 5th month.

Comment: Yes it will provide you the users which are not in for that time period and i guess this what you asked in your question also

Answer (score 0):

Your query by writing `T2.IDWorker IS NULL` restricts the set of T2 records which can go to the left join only to the ones which have `IDWorker = NULL`. The way to work around it is to create a subquery that will do the join first and then apply the filter on the result, i.e.:

```
SELECT IDWorker, Name, LastName
FROM (SELECT
      T1.IDWorker,
      T1.Name,
      T1.LastName,
      T2.IDWorker 'IDWorker2'
    FROM
      T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.IDWorker = T2.IDWorker
    WHERE
      T2.Month = 4 AND
      T2.Year = 2014) subquery
WHERE IDWorker2 IS NULL
```

*Note: Since the record in T2 won't exist in the final result, there is no point trying to print nulls for Month, Year and Factor so I removed it*

Solution suggested by sdespoint will also work but (especially for the large sets of data with indexes backed `IDWorker`) can suffer from worse performance than the option above.